# I am having issues with converting words into numerical values and I keep on getting an error code about mutase input

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been having issues with trying to convert words to numerical values. I cannot find for the life of me what is going wrong.
My code looks like below:

```
 df1 <- df1 %>%
mutate(income_num = case_when(
IncomeGroup == "Low income" ~ 1,
IncomeGroup == "Lower middle income" ~ 2,
IncomeGroup == "Upper middle income" ~ 3,
"TRUE" ~ 4))
```

My hope is to give a numerical value to the different types of incomes but I keep on getting this error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `income_num`. x object 'IncomeGroup' not found i Input `income_num` is `case_when(...)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Help will very much be appreciated.

Comment: As per the error message, check if there is a a variable called "IncomeGroup" in your df1 dataframe. Also, TRUE should not be in quotes.

Comment: can you show us (at least) the output of `names(df1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(income_num = case_when(
    IncomeGroup == "Low income" ~ "1",
    IncomeGroup == "Lower middle income" ~ "2",
    IncomeGroup == "Upper middle income" ~ "3",
    TRUE ~ "4")) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```